# Bind left join condition result from query to Entity in Spring Boot Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, nativequery

I have two tables in database, and when I make query for getting entity of one of the tables, a would like to add one additional field, that is result of condition in left join query, and this field is not in the table. When I make this query in database I getting correct result, but I don't know how to make in hibernate.

```
@Query(
        value = "SELECT c.*, r.id AS customer_response " +
                "FROM postgres.customer_form AS c " +
                "LEFT JOIN postgres.customer_responses AS r " +
                "ON c.id = r.form_id " +
                "AND r.customer_id = :customerId " +
                "WHERE c.id = :formId " +
                "LIMIT 1",
        nativeQuery = true
)
Optional<CustomerFormEntity> findById(
        @Param("formId") int formId,
        @Param("customerId") int customerId
);
```

I would like to add customer_response field in my Entity
I tried different ways, but it's not work, this is code in Entity

```
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@Transient
private Integer customer_response;
```

Comment: Please post the entity model that you are using and describe how the two tables relate to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer, I used Hibernate to get this value

this is query

```
@Query(
        value = "SELECT c FROM CustomerFormEntity c " +
                "LEFT JOIN FETCH c.customerResponse res " +
                "WHERE c.id = :formId " +
                "AND ((res IS NULL OR res.customerId = :userId) OR c.userEntity.id = :userId)"
)
Optional<CustomerFormEntity> findById(
        @Param("formId") int formId,
        @Param("userId") int userId
);
```

and this code in CustomerFormEntity

```
@OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        mappedBy = "form",
        orphanRemoval = true
)
private List<CustomerResponseEntity> customerResponse;
```

and this in CustomerResponseEntity

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "form_id")
private CustomerFormEntity form;
```